Fetching and showing SQL table data in Kivy
I'm developing a kivy app which fetches data from a sql database table, the fetched records should be showing in "rows" and "columns" in the app, with a button to the side of each record. The problem is that, in the screen that shows this data, the components that are loaded with the data are being loaded in the inferior part of the screen, instead of the top of it, therefore with more than 3 records, the rest of them are loaded out of the screen. I tried many things but I haven't been able to archieve, the following is the current code:
class MainMenu(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        # Obtener los datos de la base de datos
        data = self.get_autorizations()

        # Crear un BoxLayout vertical para organizar los componentes
        main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(1, 
None))

        # Crear un GridLayout para la tabla
        table_layout = GridLayout(cols=3, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)

        # Calcular la altura total de la tabla
        total_height = len(data) * (dp(30) + 10)  # altura de cada fila 
(30 dp) + espacio entre filas (10 dp)

        # Establecer la altura del GridLayout
        table_layout.height = total_height

        # Agregar la cabecera
        header_solicitante = Label(text="Solicitante", 
size_hint_y=None, height=dp(30), font_size=16, bold=True)
        header_fecha = Label(text="Fecha", size_hint_y=None, 
height=dp(30), font_size=16, bold=True)
        header_acciones = Label(text="Acciones", size_hint_y=None, 
height=dp(30), width=50, font_size=16, bold=True)
    
        table_layout.add_widget(header_solicitante)
        table_layout.add_widget(header_fecha)
        table_layout.add_widget(header_acciones)

        # Iterar sobre los datos y agregarlos al GridLayout
        for row_data in data:
            name_label = Label(text=str(row_data[1]), size_hint_y=None, 
height=dp(30))
            date_label = Label(text=str(row_data[2]), size_hint_y=None, 
height=dp(30))
            action_button = Button(text="Confirmar/Rechazar", 
size_hint_x=None, width=150, size_hint_y=None, height=dp(30))
            # Asignar el identificador personalizado al botón
            action_button.custom_id = str(row_data[0])
            action_button.bind(on_press=lambda instance, 
custom_id=action_button.custom_id: 
self.show_confirmation_popup(instance, custom_id))
            table_layout.add_widget(name_label)
            table_layout.add_widget(date_label)
            table_layout.add_widget(action_button)

        # Agregar la tabla al layout principal
        main_layout.add_widget(table_layout)

        # Ajustar la altura del layout principal
        main_layout.height = table_layout.height

        # Agregar el layout principal al layout de la pantalla
        self.ids.data_layout.add_widget(main_layout)


Please post your code as text. Not as an image.
